# how to disable OWASP dependency scan logs?

Tags: maven, dependencies, owasp

I don't want those logs to show, they are increasing my logs budget in prod, is there any way to hide them ?

[image]

Comment: “Logs budget in prod” and that means?

Comment: Umm dependency scan creating so many logs everytime I run it and it's been implemented in azure pipeline which is causing. The logs budget to spike and i want a way to get rid of those logs , prod as in production environment